# Python server with Elisp Emacs client

Tags: python, emacsclient, subprocess

Trying to make a small example on how to do IPC with Elisp using Python for the server. My source of information is [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processes.html#Processes)
Here is the code I have right now.

my-process.el

```
(let ((process-connection-type nil)
      (arguments (list "./server.py")))
  (apply 'start-process "my-process" "*my-process-buffer*" "python" arguments)
  (set-process-filter (get-process "my-process") 'my-callback))

(defun my-callback (process msg)
  (message msg))

(defun kill-my-process ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-process "my-process"))

(defun send-to-my-process (msg)
  (interactive "sEnter message: ")
  (process-send-string "my-process" (concat msg "\n")))

(provide my-process)
```

server.py

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("STARTING MY PROCESS!")
sys.stdout.flush()
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

The problem I have is that the process starts ok, but I can only see "STARTING MY PROCESS!" printed nothing when I do `send-to-my-process`.

My question is, what do I need to change in order for messaging to work in the above example?

Update:
Added suggested fixes.

Comment: The Jedi package uses "EPC" and a python EPC server (jediepcserver.py), you may want to check it out: https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-epc https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi

Answer (score 1):

On the elisp side, you should send a final newline to the client:

```
(process-send-string "my-process" (concat msg "\n")))
```

On the python side, you need to flush the output since you're using a pipe:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: That helped some, now "STARTING MY PROCESS!" prints in the messages buffer but still when I do send-to-my-process nothing happens.

Comment: It works for me using Python 3.  It doesn't work using Python 2, and I'm too lazy to work out why.